# Show and Hide Dialog Footer Content with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the JQuery [Dialog UI component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). This dialog is defined like the following:

```
<div id="confirmDialog" title="Are you sure?">
  Are you sure you want to delete this?
</div>
```

When I create this dialog, I am adding some content in the footer next to the buttons. I want this content to be hidden when the dialog is initially displayed. Then, when a user clicks "OK", I want to show the content and disable the buttons. In an attempt to do this, I'm currently doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Cancel: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); },
      'OK': okPress,
      'P' : function() {}
    },
    open: function(e, ui){
      $(e.target).parent().find('span').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() === 'P';
      }).parent().replaceWith('<div id=\'P1W\'>Please wait</div>');
    }
  });      
});

function okPress() {
  // Disable buttons
  // Show P1W
}
```

I have no idea how to 1) Hide the footer content initially. 2) Show the footer content when okPress is reached 3) Disable the buttons in the dialog.

In short, I guess I'm not sure how to interact with the footer contents of a JQuery Dialog. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Personally I found the workings of the jQuery UI dialog to be sufficiently unfriendly to such changes as you describe that I ended up writing my own dialog plugin.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could simply find the third button using

```
open: function(e, ui){
      $(this).find('.ui-button:nth-child(3)').replaceWith('<div id=\'P1W\'>Please wait</div>').hide();
}
```

The `.hide()` function will hide your added content immediately.

In `okPress`, you'd do

```
$('#P1W').show();
```

to show the content.

I'm not sure about this, but you might be able to disable the buttons using `$("#confirmDialog").dialog("disable");`.